# Deleting a column in a pandas frame

Tags: python, pandas

> I have been trying the past 40 minutes to delete a specific column (`Name`) from my data frame but no method seems to work. I am using jupyter notebook by the way, not sure if that may be an issue. I am also 100% sure that the column name is named `Name` and that it is not the index of the data frame -- I am using the Titanic data set.

**What I have tried:**

1. `del df['Name']`
2. `df.drop('Name', axis=1, inplace=True)`
3. `df = df.drop('Name', 1)`

All the above seem to delete the column, but when re-reading the csv the column appears back. Any clue on why this is happening?

Comment: When you are reading the original csv file, the column exists. You deleted it in only dataframe not in original csv. So, you can save the csv file with the same name after deleting the column, which will not appear if you read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read a csv to Pandas DataFrame you load the data to memory. Doing anything to data frame won't change your csv. I would suggest you export your modified dataframe as a new csv

`df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv', index = False)`

[DOCS](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

With reading a `csv` file and loading its content in a `dataframe`, you create a python object called `df`.

Then, with the three methods you showed us, you only delete some content of this object, not the `csv`'s content.

I would recommend you to use the first method, `del`, keep working with the `dataframe` and not reading the `csv` again.

Let me know if anything is unclear, please.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you reccomend on using `del`?

Comment: Sure. I just meant it fits his need. `drop` offers more features like handling multiple columns and reference copy. I don't my words to be over-interpreted, haha :)

Comment: That's why I was wondering, as drop offers way more control. But, I see your point ;)